# SQL Nearest Neighbor Query (Movie Recommendation Algorithm)

Tags: sql, algorithm, stored-procedures, nearest-neighbor

Need help making this (sort of) working query more dynamic.

I have three tables myShows, TVShows and Users

- myShows

  - ID (PK)
  - User (FK to Users)
  - Show (FK to TVShows)

Would like to take this query and change it to a stored procedure that I can send a User ID into and have it do the rest...

```
SELECT showId, name, Count(1) AS no_users
FROM
    myShows LEFT OUTER JOIN
              tvshows ON myShows.Show = tvshows.ShowId
WHERE
    [user] IN (
        SELECT [user]
           FROM
               myShows
           WHERE
               show ='1' or show='4'
          )
    AND
    show <> '1' and show <> '4'
GROUP BY
    showId, name
ORDER BY
    no_users DESC
```

This right now works. But as you can see the problem lies within the WHERE (*show ='1' or show='4'*) and the AND (*show <> '1' and show <> '4'*) statements which is currently hard-coded values, and that's what I need to be dynamic, being I have no idea if the user has 3 or 30 shows I need to check against.

Also how inefficient is this process? this will be used for a iPad application that might get a lot of users. I currently run a movie API (IMDbAPI.com) that gets about 130k hits an hour and had to do a lot of database/code optimization to make it run fast. Thanks again!

If you want the database schema for testing let me know.

Comment: Could transforming the and/or sequences to `IN ... VALUES(1),(4)...` help? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0dceb/13

Comment: I recreated this problem on sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84311/1/0
One of the core things that is missing is the [user] logic... It has no idea what shows to even check.

The sample above you will see User1 likes showId 1 and 2 and User2 likes 1 and 3, when running that query it will return 3 which is correct. But my query still has hard-coded values.

Comment: Why is 3 the correct answer in your example? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: User1 likes "Dexter" and "Archer"
User2 likes "Dexter" and "True Blood"

If User1 wants a recommendation "True Blood" should return to him because User2 watches Dexter also.

If User2 requested a recommendation it would return "Archer" because they both have Dexter in common.

it gets more complex when you add a 3rd and 4th user but that's what the count user_no is it will show how many results it found depending on people that like the same shows as you and give them a weight so sorting DESC you will see the most popular

Comment: Well, the sub-query in the WHERE clause s very dangerous. Just yesterday I removed the sub-query and reduced running time from 10+ mins to 13 secs

Comment: Also, about "_If you want the database schema for testing let me know_".
We're here to suggest stuff and help, **not write code and test it for you.**

Comment: @PranavHosangadi That's what I'm afraid of... I uploaded a new demo to sqlfiddler, it's close! but I need to remove it's own results from the output, if that makes any sense.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06beb/7/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will meet your requirements

```
select name, count(distinct [user]) from myshows recommend
inner join tvshows on recommend.show = tvshows.showid
where [user] in 
(   
    select other.[user] from 
        ( select show from myshows where [User] = @user ) my,
        ( select show, [user] from myshows where [user] <> @user ) other
    where my.show = other.show
)   
and show not in ( select show from myshows where [User] = @user ) 
group by name
order by count(distinct [user]) desc
```

If your SQL platform supports `WITH` Common Table Expressions, the above can be optimized to use them.

Will it be efficient as the data sizes increase? No. 
Will it be effective? No. If just one user shares a show with your selected user, and they watch a popular show, then that popular show will rise to the top of the ranking.

I'd recommend

a) reviewing your thinking of what recommends a show

b) periodically calculating the results rather than performing it on demand.

Comment: That worked! Also once I added the "And xxx Not In" to my query it removed it's own results which is what I was currently stuck on! Thanks. Also nothing is "popular" in the database till a lot of users add it, and they would have to share a lot of the same shows in common for the count() weight to get higher. If you watch A and B and 5,000 other people watch A or B and C... Maybe you should checkout C? That's how it would work.

Comment: Yes. But if I watch Croquet and Real Tennis and one gazillion people watch Football, and one person watches Football and Croquet, should I try Football? Or am I more likely to be interested in what other people who watch *both* Croquet and Real Tennis like....? And then it gets more interesting/complicated....

Comment: This uses a sub-query in WHERE which is a bad, BAD practice. For the reason, see my comment to the question

Comment: In that case Football would only have a weight of 1 and hopefully more relevant stuff will surpass it. It's only going to show a top 5... No system is perfect I guess, most of the stuff TV.com tells me to watch I don't like -heh

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Do you have any documented evidence to back up that assertion, other than the single example you have encountered?

Comment: @podiluska see the second point on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html **"Subquery optimization for IN is not as effective as for the = operator or for the IN(value_list) operator."**

Comment: @PranavHosangadi An example of poor optimization by a particular database platform is hardly an example of bad practice. No-one had mentioned mysql until now

Comment: @podiluska, I just gave you a real life example of what I experienced, just showed you proof that sub-queries can shatter performance, and you are still adamant that it is not _bad practice_ !! MySQL and MS SQL have similarities, and this is one of them. Stop thinking that I'm doing this to find faults with you, I merely said that to stress the performance issues that the OP *might* have if he/she uses sub-queries.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi "Can have performance issues" is fundamentally different to "bad, bad practice". Just because an effect can occur in certain situations doesn't make it bad practice, any more than claiming that you should always write a query in certain way because it once performed in 2ms.  This is going nowhere.

Comment: @podiluska It is a bad practice for the sole reason that it can create performance issues. If you're aiming to write a real-world query of at least some reliability, you should try to write it such that it will handle any amount of data. Considering the OP's application is a movie database, one can safely assume that there will be quite a lot of rows in the tables, which is exactly the time when your sub-queried script will fail you. I agree that this is going nowhere, so discussion closed :)